# Проблема при установке(добавлении react)

Tags: reactjs

[image: 1]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxMaS.png):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Установлен node.js но когда пишу npx create-react-app app_01 выходит вот такая ошибка.Кто-то знает как это можно решить?

Comment: У вас папка app_01 Существует? Она пустая?

Comment: у меня файл app_01 Существует он не пустой.

Comment: app_01 должна быть директория, а не файл

Comment: Ну вот я на диске E создал папку app_01 и она пустая .В ней жму Git bash here и ввожу npx create-react-app app_01 и выдает туже ошибку. Или я что-то не так сделал?

Comment: выйдите из папки app_01 и запустите вашу команду

Comment: Я нажал  в диске Е    git bash here и ввел npx create-react-app app_01 ,но всеравно получил туже ошибку.

Comment: Команда `node -v` что выводит? И в какой директории у вас установлен nodejs?

Comment: $ node -v   
v18.12.1
nodejs установлен на диске E:\nudejs .Я его переустанавливал раз 5-6 может быть в этом какая-то проблема.

Comment: Судя по скрину, запуск или поиск осуществляется из другой директории...

Comment: Ладно,спасибо что пытались мне помочь.Видимо придется виндовс переустановить.